# Parent id field of feed item object

Tags: attachment, feeditem, id

The FeedItem object is used in my Org. There is a field called parent ID. But i am not being able to understand to which object is FeedItem related to? is there a way to see which object is parent id referring to in my org?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a reference of type [ID](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_id.htm) (such as your FeedItem parent ID) you can directly get the type token of the object (in this case the parent object) and add whatever dependent logic you need:

```
Id parentId = ...;
SObjectType sobType = parentId.getSObjectType();

if (sobType == Contact.SObjectType) {
    ...
}
```

That logic can use hard-coded types as above or can make use of [describe calls](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm) to find out the relevant information.